# finetuning EfficientDet-D0 from model zoo on PASCALVOC doesn't recognize class label 1 (TensorFlow Object Detection API)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I've downloaded the EfficientDet D0 512x512 model from the object detection API model zoo, downloaded the PASCAL VOC dataset and preprocessed it with the `create_pascal_tf_record.py` file. Next I took one of the config files and adjusted it to fit the architecture and VOC dataset. When evaluating the resulting network with the `pascal_voc_detection_metrics` it gives me a near zero mAP for the first class (airplane), the other classes are performing fine. I'm assuming one of my settings in the config file is wrong (pasted down below), why does this happen and how do i fix this?

```
model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 20
    add_background_class: false
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
        scales_per_octave: 3
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
        }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        depth: 64
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          force_use_bias: true
          activation: SWISH
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            scale: true
            decay: 0.99
            epsilon: 0.001
          }
        }
        num_layers_before_predictor: 3
        kernel_size: 3
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_efficientnet-b0_bifpn_keras'
      bifpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        num_iterations: 3
        num_filters: 64
      }
      conv_hyperparams {
        force_use_bias: true
        activation: SWISH
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          scale: true,
          decay: 0.99,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.25
          gamma: 1.5
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "oracle/efficientdet_d0/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  batch_size: 3
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  use_bfloat16: false
  num_steps: 30000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
      output_size: 512
      scale_min: 0.1
      scale_max: 2.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 8e-2
          total_steps: 30000
          warmup_learning_rate: .001
          warmup_steps: 2500
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  update_trainable_variables: ["WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor"]
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "pascalVOC/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "pascalVOC/pascal_train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "pascalVOC/pascal_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "pascalVOC/pascal_val.record"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the way `pascal_voc_detection_metrics` calculates the metric, fix can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/9956)